# Can't get USB output from another device using paramiko

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, usb, paramiko

I want to controle an Frequency Synthesizer whith a remote device using Python 2.7.

The communication directly using an USB port from a Rapberry Pi is done via Terminal.The commands are found in the manual. There are two kind of commands, set and get, e.g.:

```
echo 0E > /dev/ttyACM0    # 0E is the code to reset
echo 04 > /dev/ttyACM0|head</dev/ttyACM0    # 04 will return the frequency
```

I use the following code to get the output in python on my Raspberry:

```
print(os.popen(echo 04 > /dev/ttyACM0|head</dev/ttyACM0))
```

The Terminal command can be executed using ssh from another device.

Now, when I try to use Python, I can use set commands with no probelms, but get commands won't bring the correct output.

I use the following function:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
global Con # nected
con=0


        def SSHConnection():
            global con
            while True:
                try:
                    ssh.connect(IP,username=User,password=Password)
                    con=1
                    break
                except:
                    tkMessageBox.showwarning("Error!", "Device not found or wrong Login")
                    break

        def outin(command):
            global con
            output="sudo echo "+command+"> /dev/ttyACM0|head</dev/ttyACM0"
            if remote.get()==0:  # switches between remote and direct output
                answer=os.popen(output).readlines()
            else:
                if con==0:  #  checks wether a connection has already 
                    SSHConnection()  #  connects
                else:
                    pass
                stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(output)
                answer=stdout.read()
            return answer
```

I found online that my function might do the `.read()` before my command was executed.
All solutions I found online were using the `channel.recv_exit_status()`-function, which got me stuck in an loop.

I'd be very glad if someone could help me.

Edit:
The wrong output is in fact `0x0096` = 150 which is not that wrong, but usually the last request I send.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is some kind of timing.
I did a workaround by calling a python-code on the remote device to save the output in a different file, and then call the file.
Does work in about 98% of the calls ..